# Serving sites on multiple ports with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, proxy

Looking for this solution for a while now and think I'm pretty close, however...
So I have 5 different VMs running webpages on different ports. For brevity sake lets say 8080 to 8484. I want to have them all listen on 127.0.0.1 and their respective port. I also want nginx to serve as an https and password protected front to a landing page that will redirect the users to these internal sites.

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/home.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/home.key;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;
client_max_body_size 101M;
auth_basic "Login required";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

    location /server1 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

    location /server2 {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
    proxy_set_header Host \$host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

....

So this will prompt me for the user, pass and redirect to the appropriate page being hosted on that port, but I get an error saying disallowed host at /server1 for an invalid HTTP_HOST header as \127.0.0.1 is not valid.

Is this even possible to do? The servers are running various frameworks, Django, Apache, Tomcat...

Comment: Why do you want the backslash as a prefix in the host header?

Comment: Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ]

Comment: Do I need a \ prefix?

Comment: So how do I set the proxy headers correctly? Not sure what the GET request looks like.

Comment: You don't want the backslash.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to escape every $ in there. Try removing all those backslahes.

Comment: Ok. I took those out and now it redirects me site.local/server1 but I am getting a  404.

Comment: So the taking out the / worked, I just had to add one after the ip and the location

Comment: Didn't know about that Slash at the end being required but I it makes sense. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/home.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/home.key;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;
client_max_body_size 101M;
auth_basic "Login required";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;

    location /server1/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

    location /server2/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```